# Mac program like WinSCP

Tags: mac, sync, winscp

I'm looking for a program on Mac that does one thing exactly like WinSCP: listens to file changes in directories and uploads the changed files to a remote server, thus keeping them in sync: remote synchronization. I expect it to work exactly like the same feature in WinSCP. I'd prefer it to be free. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org) and a little [launchd](http://developer.apple.com/macosx/launchd.html) fiddling, you can roll your own. Set up a launchd task that monitors your chosen file, and when it changes, runs rsync to copy things over to your server. If you're new to launchd, I recommend [Lingon](http://lingon.sourceforge.net/) as a GUI.

Also, if you're only doing this for a few files and depending on how much access you have to the server, [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) may be a lot easier to set up.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Transmit](http://www.panic.com/transmit/)

Comment: I really like transmit, especially the "sync" feature

Comment: Does it do this: "listens to file changes in directories and uploads the changed files to a remote server"? I need it to automatically upload files when I make changes to the local copy.

Comment: I too am looking for this. I want to set a local and remote, then when I edit something in local it reflects in remote. Transmit has "sync" but that syncs everything and not just what was edited.

Answer (score 3):

[CyberDuck](http://cyberduck.ch/) is a nice file transfer program for the OS X.  It will do SCP as well as sync your local folder with the remote.

Comment: does it do it automatically when I save a file?

Answer (score 1):

[FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) is a good alternative to WinsCP. It is Open Source and cross platform with remote directory search feature. See its Features  [here](http://filezilla-project.org/client_features.php) . Its Free.

Comment: Does it do remote synchronization? It doesn't seem to according to the features list...

Comment: I haven't tried the remote synchronization yet , but if it says then it does.